# Как правильно получить данные из form и отправить их GET-запросом?

Tags: javascript

По заданию мне нужно взять из form данные (x, y, r) и передать их с помощью GET-запроса. Я понимаю, что это надо сделать с помощью url, но как правильно получить эти данные? Вот нерабочий вариант:

```js
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("coordinates-form"));
    const sendButt = document.getElementById("submit-button");
    const submit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("php/get_data.php?x=" + formData.get("x") + "&y=" + formData.get("y")
         + "&r=" + formData.get("r")).then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => document.getElementById('result-table').innerHTML = response);
    };
    sendButt.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

Вот моя форма.

```
                <div class="X-radios">
                    <h4>X:</h4>
                    <label class="x-element-label">-3
                        <input class="x_radio" type="radio" name="x" value="-3">
                    </label>
                    // еще пару штук таких
                </div>
                <label class="Y-element-label"> Y:
                    <input id="y-text" class="y-text-input" type="text" name="y" placeholder="y value" required/>
                </label>
                <span id="value-validate-text"></span>
                <div class="R-checkboxes" id="R">
                    <h4>R:</h4>
                    <label class="r-element-label">1
                        <input class="r-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="r" value="1" checked>
                    </label>
                    // еще пару штук таких
                </div>
                <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                <button id="clear-button"type="reset">Очистить</button>
            </form>
```

В адресной строке нормально показываются параметры, однако через get() класса FormData не получается. Как можно их получить и как правильно сделать запрос?

Comment: А что такое `formData`?

Comment: извиняюсь, добавил строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите

`var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("coordinates-form"));`

внутрь функции

`const submit = function (e) {...`